# How to run python script in certain conda environment in regular time intervals under Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10, conda

I want to run a certain python script every 5 min or so to automate some tasks under Windows 10.

[Here](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/analytics/scheduling-a-python-script-or-model-to-run-at-a-prescribed-time/?rmedium=redirect&rsource=blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip) is a description of how to run a python script frequently under Win 7. Does W10 have the same or similar task scheduler? Are there better ways of doing it?

Also, I would like to load a conda environment before the script is executed. Has anyone done that before? Does anyone have a link to a description?

Comment: Task scheduler still exists so you can still use it to schedule a script to run. Could you explain why you want to load a conda environment?

Comment: I want to load a conda environment, because I may need to run different scripts with different dependencies which are mutually incompatible.

Comment: Have you considered [compiling your script into an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency) and then running that? This has the advantage that you're not going to break the functionality if something happens to your conda environment. Not sure if it's a better alternative, but I've made that work before when scheduling a Python script to run as a scheduled task.